# Placing transformers in parallel to increase current

Tags: power-supply, transformer, isolation

I am trying to create an isolated 5V 1.5A power supply. After doing some research, I decided to go with a SN6505 to driver a transformer to gain isolation. However, maximum current output of the driver is 1A; so I am thinking of using two of them and tied the output together to have the maximum output of 2A. My question is: Will the current drawn from both transformer will be equal to each other and be equal to half of the total current? i.e 750mA from each circuit if total required output is 1.5A.

My intention: unregulated source: 20-50Vdc -> buck converter: 5Vdc -> (SN6505 + transformer)x2: isolation -> LDO: regulated 5Vdc.
Second question: Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I have a look at flyback converters but have really hard time finding the transformer that works for the required voltage range.

Comment: Those are independently controlled and will fight in parallel. Have you considered a simple flyback supply instead e.g. UC3842?

Comment: I can’t seem to find any readily available flyback transformer on Digikey or Mouser that works for me. They either have very low turns ratio or low current rating.

Comment: A turns ratio from 1:1 to 10:1 would be usable. It's a shame the parametric searches aren't better for these sorts of things, but alas. What isolation do you need, anyway?

Comment: I need isolation for a RS-485 transceiver in order to run an additional ground wire between devices along with the differential pair.

Comment: Why so much current? What ground loop voltage are you expecting?

Comment: Well I have a whole bunch of them on the main controller, each controls different sections of the system; therefore I need a lot of current to drive all of them. Regarding ground loop voltage, I don’t know what to expect since this is the first time I build this system and don’t really have much experience on RS-485.

Comment: Whole bunch of---485 channels?  Were you expecting to power all of them in parallel? Is that a good idea (say if one transceiver fails short, it would sink the full current of the supply, not just its ~200mA share)?  Do they need to be individually isolated? Perhaps taking a step back and considering the system (isolation and immunity requirements, number of channels, emissions if applicable, number of channels and relative grounding or full isolation, etc.) would be prudent. RS-485 deals with a fair amount of ground loop itself (~8V) so doesn't always need isolation.

Comment: Yes I wanted to power them all in parallel. I am thinking of placing a current limiting circuit for each of them; so in case of one failing short, the current limiting circuit will just cut out the power for that failed channel. No I don’t need to isolate them individually, which is the reason why I am trying to figure out how to design a power line to power all of them. Right now, the isolation is only provisional. As mentioned, I haven’t worked on any system that uses RS-485; therefore I don’t exactly know what to expect. Isolation will only be used if needed, and I can use the same PCB.